# Getting Issues while VSTS Integration with Jenkins using Service Hooks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

[As part of CI,I want to integrate VSTS with Jenkins using Service Hooks,Here are the Steps i perform.

1.After selecting Jenkins Service option, I am entering the Jenkins details as per below image.

2.Jenkins base URL, User name, User API Token are entered but Build Textbox is not allowing me enter any value.

Build Error Log using Build and Release:-

```
2017-06-23T12:46:02.5702001Z ##[section]Starting: Build
2017-06-23T12:46:02.5721999Z Current agent version: '2.119.1'
2017-06-23T12:46:03.0032004Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize Job
2017-06-23T12:46:03.0122005Z Prepare build directory.
2017-06-23T12:46:03.0431992Z Set build variables.
2017-06-23T12:46:03.0471996Z Download all required tasks.
2017-06-23T12:46:03.0601994Z Downloading task: JenkinsQueueJob
2017-06-23T12:46:03.7031992Z Downloading task: JenkinsDownloadArtifacts
2017-06-23T12:46:05.7861997Z Downloading task: PublishTestResults
2017-06-23T12:46:05.9391998Z Downloading task: PublishBuildArtifacts
2017-06-23T12:46:06.1041998Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize Job
2017-06-23T12:46:06.1351993Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2017-06-23T12:46:06.1711981Z Syncing repository: MyFirstProject (TfsGit)
2017-06-23T12:46:06.1761997Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
2017-06-23T12:46:06.1842000Z ##[command]git version
2017-06-23T12:46:06.4442001Z git version 2.12.0.windows.1
2017-06-23T12:46:06.4561989Z ##[command]git init "d:\a\1\s"
2017-06-23T12:46:06.5122094Z Initialized empty Git repository in d:/a/1/s/.git/
2017-06-23T12:46:06.5151998Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://ramandogra.visualstudio.com/_git/MyFirstProject
2017-06-23T12:46:06.5371993Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2017-06-23T12:46:06.5571999Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://ramandogra.visualstudio.com/_git/MyFirstProject.extraheader
2017-06-23T12:46:06.5761994Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2017-06-23T12:46:06.6061997Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress origin
2017-06-23T12:46:07.4221999Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/origin/master
2017-06-23T12:46:07.4431999Z error: pathspec 'refs/remotes/origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
2017-06-23T12:46:07.6841986Z ##[error]Git checkout failed with exit code: 1
2017-06-23T12:46:07.6881995Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
2017-06-23T12:46:07.6901995Z ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
2017-06-23T12:46:07.6951999Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: MyFirstProject (Git)
2017-06-23T12:46:07.6992000Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://ramandogra.visualstudio.com/_git/MyFirstProject
2017-06-23T12:46:07.7211998Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://ramandogra.visualstudio.com/_git/MyFirstProject
2017-06-23T12:46:07.7401991Z ##[section]Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
2017-06-23T12:46:07.7461997Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

PS: I am first time user of VSTS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can your Jenkins server be accessed from internet?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT No, it cannot be exposed to Internet.I have no rights to turn off my windows Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly caused your jenkins base URL is a local address, such as http://computername:8080 (or http://ip:8080). But the URL can’t be reached by others.

Do below things to check if local URL can be used:

1. In http://localhost:8080/configure, use the Jenkins URL as Jenkins base URL for service hook.
   [image]
2. Turn off firewall for your local machine.

Comment: I am doing everything on local. Instead of putting http ://localhost:8080, i am putting the value http ://fullpcname:8080.

Comment: I am not sure if local URL can be used in service hook jenkins. But you can double check with there settings which I added in my answer.

Comment: Hi Marina, I tried Server URL as http://ipaddress:8080/configure and gettting Operation Time Out Error.
Failed to query service endpoint api: http://ipaddress:8080/api/json?tree=jobs[name,displayName]. Error Message: The operation has timed out. 
Note: Verification may fail if the URL is not accessible from Visual Studio Team Services. However it might still be valid and accessible from the agent that executes Build/Release.

Comment: I mean you should use jenkins URL as the picture shows `http://10.168.173.8.:8080`.

Comment: -MSFT, I think i am correctly entering my IP there. http://ipaddress:8080

Comment: Trying now using Build and Release, Connection is created but My Build getting Failed. Here are the Build Logs

Comment: Hi Marina, now I am using Build and Release but my Build getting failed. Pasted Error Log in the Question Content.

Comment: Does `master` branch exist in the git repo which you build for jenkins?

Comment: No, Master Branch is there in the Code Section of VSTS. Whereas I am not storing anything in the Git.